# How to get the correct css selector for selenium (python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, automated-tests

I try to automate some stuff. If I identify the css selector with selenium IDE I get the correct address most of the time.
If I use the inspect mode of chrome or firefox developers edition, I don't. I do not understand why that is, or how to fix this.

Also is there a possiblity to check the

```
data-testid="801212545-follow"
```

if it contains "follow"?

I used the following:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".css-1dbjc4n:nth-child(1) > .css-18t94o4:nth-child(1) > .css-901oao > .css-901oao > .css-901oao")
for elem in elements:
   print(f"{elem}")
```

To get

```
<div class="css-1dbjc4n" data-testid="placementTracking"><div class="css-1dbjc4n r-15d164r" style="min-width: 94px;"><div role="button" data-focusable="true" tabindex="0" class="css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-urgr8i r-42olwf r-sdzlij r-1phboty r-rs99b7 r-1w2pmg r-1vuscfd r-1dhvaqw r-1ny4l3l r-1fneopy r-o7ynqc r-6416eg r-lrvibr" data-testid="801212545-unfollow"><div dir="auto" class="css-901oao r-1awozwy r-jwli3a r-6koalj r-18u37iz r-16y2uox r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-b88u0q r-1777fci r-eljoum r-dnmrzs r-bcqeeo r-q4m81j r-qvutc0"><span class="css-901oao css-16my406 css-bfa6kz r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0"><span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">Folge ich</span></span></div></div></div></div>
```

There is "Folge", but the script returns:

> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
> (session="bc2ab192ac38c886f3c48888e8cce1bf",
> element="9fbeadc8-bbae-42cc-a5b4-e5d38f2c7f87")>

Answer (score 0):

To identify the element:

```
data-testid="801212545-follow"
```

You can use the following [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors):

```
[data-testid$='follow']
```

Where, the expression `data-testid$='follow'` checks for the value of `data-testid` attribute to end with `follow`